# Why can't I send an email with name 'New Message' to a Gmail account?

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

Running PHP 5.6 via XAMPP on a Windows 8 64-bit machine.

I am using PHPMailer to send emails. If I set this:

```
    $mail->FromName = 'New Message';
```

The message will not get delivered to my gmail account. It doesn't go to the spam folder, I just don't see it. Further, PHPMailer reveals no errors. I can send it to my private domain name with the same FromName, and I receive it fine. Any other FromName works fine to my gmail account.

If I set my name in MS Outlook to 'New Message' and send an email to my gmail account, I receive the email.

Is there some RFC guideline I'm not adhering to?

N.B. Yes, putting FromName as "New Message" is stupid. It wasn't intentional, but I have no idea why the message won't be received by Google.

---

PHPMailer Setup:

```
    $this->mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $this->mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $this->mail->Host = "myhosting.com";  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = $this->config["auth"];                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $this->mail->Username = "myusername@mydomain.com";                 // SMTP username
    $this->mail->Password = "xxxx";                           // SMTP password
    $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $this->mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $this->mail->From = $from;
    $this->mail->FromName = $fromName;
    $this->mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient

    $this->mail->isHTML(true);        // Set email format to HTML

    $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
    $this->mail->Body    = $message;

    if(!$this->mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception("Message could not be sent. Error: ".$this->mail->ErrorInfo);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you leave FromName blank? How do you technically send the email? SMTP? If so, is the SMTP server configured correctly? More code would be helpful.

Comment: @l-x I've added code, it's the stock standard example code though. Yes, SMTP through SSL. I'm not hosting the SMTP server, it's my hosting provider so I wouldn't know that.

Comment: If you send through Outlook, is it going through the same server? If it's getting to that server and then not getting to gmail, the reason will be shown in the mail server logs. Next step would be to send directly to your gmail account - I just tested your config directly with gmail, and it has no problem sending with a from name of 'New Message'. This suggests it's your mail server that's doing something odd.

Comment: @Synchro Yes, I'm using the same host, username, etc. in Outlook as in my code. What do you mean send directly to my gmail account? The "to" field is `mygmailaccount@gmail.com`.

Comment: As in set `Username` and `Password` to your gmail account and send through gmail instead of through your normal mail server. I've now tested it both ways around (sending both from and to gmail), and this `FromName` has no problems.

Comment: @Synchro PHPMailer + Gmail Account and server works fine, so it must be my mail server?

Comment: You need to see its log files to be sure, but it looks that way.

Answer (score 0):

probably the spamshield stuff google uses, it gets a lot of bot traffic and discards a huge abount of improperly configured mail. you should see the same thing happen if you put text in the time field, for example.

Comment: Are you saying it's the way PHPMailer compiles the message, and that Outlook does it correctly?

Comment: No, i was more thinking that because you have probably emailed your gmail from your outlook client before it may be allowing the email through. is your Gmail account configured in outlook? if you disable it and just try sending an email then, does it still go through?

Comment: I have used this email address with the same gmail account before though... And no - I use the web browser to access my gmail account (as well as phone, tablet, etc. but not Outlook)